# Translate C to MIPS code (understanding memory access in MIPS)

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Assume that the variables f and g are assigned to registers $s0, $s1. Assume that the base address of the arrays A and B are in registers $s6 and $s7 respectively. Below is the MIPS code I have written to translate A[2*(f+g)] = B[B[16 + f/2] ]:

```
# accessing the correct address for A[2*(f+g)] 
line 1. add $t0, $s0, $s1    # $t0 = f + g
line 2. add $s6, $s6, $t0    # A[0] should update to A[(f+g)/4]
line 3. sll $s6, $s6, 3      # A[(f+g)/4] should update to A[(8*((f+g)/4)]

line 4. srl $s0, $s0, 1      # f = f/2
line 5. addi $s0, $s0, 16    # f = f/2 + 16
line 6. sll $s0, $s0, 2      # f = (f/2 + 16) * 4
line 7. add $s7, $s0, $s7    # B[0] should update to B[f/2 + 16] 

line 8. sll $s7, $s7, 2      # B[f/2 + 16] should update to (B[f/2 + 16]) * 4
line 9. add $t0, $s7, $0     # $t0 = (B[f/2 + 16]) * 4
line 10. sw $s6, $t0($s7)     # should be storing B[(B[f/2 + 16]) * 4] in A[2*(f+g)]
```

I think that I am messing up with access the memory location inside of array B when you need to access it twice. Can someone help?

Comment: Comment every instruction with what you want them to do (logically). In any case `$t0($s7)` is surely invalid and you never read from B, not even once, let alone twice.

Comment: There is no starting MIPS code. All you have is which registers point to which variable. Ex.: f = $s0, g = $s1, A[0] = $s6, B[0] = $s7. I don't understand why you would be reading from B?

Comment: What do you think `B[x]` means if not reading?

Comment: That you are accessing memory at location x in array B

Comment: Otherwise known as reading from memory or in MIPS parlance, a load. You are not doing that at all. You are correctly calculating the address of the first read but never do the read itself. You will need an `lw` instruction for that. You should put the address somewhere else than `$s7` so as to preserve the base address of `B` for the second read.

Comment: `add $s6, $s6, $t0` `sll $s6, $s6, 3` looks wrong to me. I think you need to multiply up the offset before you add it to A; as it stands you're shifting the A pointer too.

Comment: @Rup, do you mean I should have: `sll $t0, $t0, 3` and `add $s6, $s6, $t0` instead?

Comment: I think so, yes. Apologies my MIPS is rusty.

Comment: @Jester, would I replace lines #8 - #10 with the following: `lw $t1, 0($s7)` `sll $t1, $t1, 2)` `add $s7, $s7, $t1` `sw $s6, 0($s7)`. Would this solve the problems?

Comment: Pretty much but you will need another `lw` for the second read.

Comment: @Jester, I think I have fixed everything in my proposed answer

Comment: Looks about right at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct solution is the following:

```
add $t0, $s0, $s1
sll $t0, $t0, 3
add $s6, $t0, $s6

srl $t1, $s0, 1
addi $t1, $t1, 16
sll $t1, $t1, 2
add $t2, $s7, $t1
lw $t3, 0($t2)
add t4, $s7, $t3
lw $t5, 0($t4)
sw $t5, 0($s6)
```